# Semantic issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

[image]

As seen in the picture, i am receiving a semantic issue on GADMobileAds. Previously i have imported Google Mobile Ads framework manually by putting it in the root of the app then put it in the framework folder. This solved the error of 'Framework google mobile ads not found'.

However after trying to delete derived data and clean build app, i tried to build it, it showed me this error instead. Please help!

Comment: See if there is anything left out under Build Phases.

Comment: Is the framework listed under "Link Binaries With Libraries" section of "Build Phases" in project navigator?

Comment: yes already added it inside.

Comment: sometimes it shows this semantic error sometimes it shows module 'googlemobileads' not found

Comment: pls check Framework search path in build settings.